# GWT Request Factory - Multiple queries for collection from the "ServiceLayerDecorator.isLive()" - method

Tags: java, gwt, requestfactory

I had the problem, that every time i retrieved a collection from the gwt request factory, there was the "findEntity()"-method called for every entity in that collection. And this "findEntity()"-method calls the SQL-Database.

I found out that this happens because request factory checks the "liveness" of every entity in the "ServiceLayerDecorator.isLive()"-method (also described here: [requestfactory and findEntity method in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083346/requestfactory-and-findentity-method-in-gwt))

So i provided my own RequestFactoryServlet:

```
public class MyCustomRequestFactoryServlet extends RequestFactoryServlet {


    public MyCustomRequestFactoryServlet() {
        super(new DefaultExceptionHandler(), new MyCustomServiceLayerDecorator());

    }

}
```

And my own ServiceLayerDecorator:

```
public class MyCustomServiceLayerDecorator extends ServiceLayerDecorator {

    /**
     * This check does normally a lookup against the db for every element in a collection
     * -> Therefore overridden
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isLive(Object domainObject) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This works so far and I don't get this massive amount of queries against the database.

Now I am wondering if I will get some other issues with that? Or is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RequestFactory expects a session-per-request pattern with the *session* guaranteeing a single instance per entity (i.e. using a cache).

The proper *fix* is to have `isLive` hit that cache, not the database. If you use JPA or JDO, they should do that for you for free. What matters is what "the request" *thinks* about it (if you issued a delete request, `isLive` should return `false`), not really what's exactly stored in the DB, taking into account what other users could have done concurrently.

That being said, `isLive` is only used for driving `EntityProxyChange` events on the client side, so if you don't use them, it shouldn't cause any problem unconditionally returning `true` like you do.